# How to do a Correlation of various Raster Data and show the result in a Correlation Matrix

Tags: interpolation, kriging, correlation, raster-dataset

I am doing spatial correlation of soil Data sets.
I did various Kiriging Interpolations with the krige function. The output was cut to a target raster to have the same raster size for all Kriging Interpolations of my datasets.

Usually to do a correlation between two kriging outputs I use the cor.test function method = "pearson". Later I copy and paste the Consule result to Excel and calculate the r-squared and creat a Correlation Matrix.
But now I have so much Kriging output that it would take forever to do everything manually!

Is there a possibility to do a correlation of all Kriging Output (Formal Class SpatialGridDataFrame) with one function and demonstrate the result in a Correlation Matrix?